# Scrapy crawler to parse data recursively can not call back

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a newbie and I've written a script in python scrapy to get information recursively.

Firstly, it scrapes links of city including information of tours then it tracks down each cities and reach their pages. Next, it get needed information of tours related to city before move to next pages then so on. Pagination is running on java-script without visible link.

The command I used to get the result along with a csv output is:

```
scrapy crawl pratice -o practice.csv -t csv
```

The expected result is csv file:

```
title, city, price, tour_url
t1, c1, p1, url_1
t2, c2, p2, url_2
...
```

The problem is that csv file is empty. The running is stopped at "parse_page" and callback="self.parse_item" doesn't work. I don't know how to fix it. Maybe my workflow is invalid or my code has issues. Thanks for your help.

```
name = 'practice'
start_urls = ['https://www.klook.com/vi/search?query=VI%E1%BB%86T%20NAM%20&type=country',]

def parse(self, response): # Extract cities from country
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    urls = hxs.select("//div[@class='swiper-wrapper cityData']/a/@href").extract()
    for url in urls:
        url = urllib.parse.urljoin(response.url, url)
        self.log('Found city url: %s' % url)
        yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_page) # Link to city


def parse_page(self, response): # Move to next page
    url_ = response.request.url
    yield response.follow(url_, callback=self.parse_item)

    # I will use selenium to move next page because of next button is running
    # on javascript without fixed url.

def parse_item(self, response): # Extract tours
    for block in response.xpath("//div[@class='m_justify_list m_radius_box act_card act_card_lg a_sd_move j_activity_item js-item ']"):
        article = {}
        article['title'] = block.xpath('.//h3[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
        article['city'] = response.xpath(".//div[@class='g_v_c_mid t_mid']/h1/text()").extract()# fixed
        article['price'] = re.sub("  +","",block.xpath(".//span[@class='latest_price']/b/text()").extract_first()).strip()
        article['tour_url'] = 'www.klook.com'+block.xpath(".//a/@href").extract_first()

        yield article
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)    #response is already in Selector, use direct `response.xpath`

url = urllib.parse.urljoin(response.url, url)
```

use as:

url = response.urljoin(url)

yes it will stop as its a duplicate request to prev. url, you need to add `dont_filter=True` check

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Selenium, figure out what request the website performs using JavaScript (watch the Network tab of the developer tools of your browser while you navigate) and reproduce a similar request.

The website uses JSON requests undernead to fetch the items, which is much easier to parse than the HTML.

Also, if you are not familiar with Scrapy’s asynchronous nature, you are likely to get unexpected issues while using it in combination with Selenium.

Solutions like Splash or Selenium are only meant to be used as last resource, when everything else fails.